# How can one set the url of an ajax call to open in a new window

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an ajax call with a url. Just wondering if it is possible to set that url to open in a blank tab or window. I don't know much in ajax yet. So any help, with some explanation, would be much appreciated. Below is the code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'membership/fetchParishionersDetails.php',
    method: "POST",
    data: {view:view},
    type: "json",
    success:function(response)
    {
        var x =JSON.parse(response);

        $('.dropdown-menu').html(x.notification);
        if(view !='')
            localStorage.setItem("noteCount",0);
        if(x.unseen_notification >=localStorage.getItem("noteCount")) {

            if(x.unseen_notification > localStorage.getItem("noteCount")) {

                if(x.unseen_notification>localStorage.getItem("noteCount")) {
                    var audio = new Audio('membership/sounds/beep1.wav');
                    audio.play();
                }

                localStorage.setItem("noteCount",x.unseen_notification);
                $('.count').html(x.unseen_notification);
            }

        }

    }
});
```

I tried doing this

```
url: ('membership/fetchParishionersDetails.php','_blank'),
```

but it did not work

Comment: It does it in the background, ajax won't work like that. You can OPEN a page, by doing  window opener in the function success area

Comment: If your boss told you to go fetch the server from the server room, would you expect the server to appear in a different building? XHR is a bound, two way comm protocol between source and sync - not source to somewhere else.

Comment: @clearshot66 first of all thanks for your response.I was actually modifiying a website that has a notification system that pops up and the notice can be clicked which then takes you to a page. But the page opens in the same window. That was why i asked if it was possible at all to open that page in a new tab. What can be the best way to go about ensuring the new page loads in a new tab and not in the same window?

Answer (score 1):

Ajax calls are meant to be used as a client-side request mechanism, not to open tabs. You won't be able to open your AJAX request in any window at all, as its executed in the background by the browser